# What is the first occurrence of a pre-teen female superhero in comics?

Tags: comics, history-of, female-characters

I am looking for the first appearance of a female heroine that would generally be considered a super-human and who is under the age of 13. *[Wonder Tot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wonder_Girl)* comes to mind, but is this the first?

Comment: I can find some teen heroes, but pre-teen is pretty tough.

Comment: @Keen Why did you delete your Freckles Marvel answer? Was she a real superhero, or was she a fake like Uncle Marvel?

Comment: @user14111 Because upon further reading, she wasn't super.  Before that, I deleted when I realized Jean Grey started as a teenager.

Comment: For information, the first appearance of [Wonder Tot](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Wonder_Tot_%28Earth-124.1%29) was **August, 1961**. This information is essential to answering the question, but is not available in the asker's Wiki link.

Comment: Are you looking for traditional "dress up in tights" heroes? Otherwise, I'd be inclined to go for Hercules, already strangling snakes in his crib. Did Gilgamesh do anything in diapers? :-P

Comment: Gilgamesh in diapers sounds like a punk rock band.

Comment: @SeanDuggan Wait. Hercules was a girl?

Comment: Only in my fanfiction... and yeah, totally missed the gender. :-P

Comment: @SeanDuggan Hercules is the wrong sex, but what about Athena? She was born a full-grown goddess (at least in some versions), so was she a "pre-teen superhero" for the first 13 years of her existence? Also, **when did she first appear in a comic**, because the question specifies "in comics".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Possibly...

**Mary Marvel**, First Appearance in Captain Marvel Adventures #18 (December 1942)]

According to [her Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_Marvel):

> She is the alter ego of teenager Mary Batson (adopted name Mary
>   Bromfield), twin sister of Captain Marvel's alter-ego, Billy Batson.
>   Like her brother, Mary has been granted the power of the wizard
>   Shazam, and has but to speak the wizard's name to be transformed into
>   the superpowered Mary Marvel.

I think she fits the age constraint because her twin brother, Billy (Captain Marvel's alter-ego), is 12 on her début.

*Edit:*
I've had to go through a bit of internet-hopping to prove that she's twelve and if anyone has evidence otherwise, please shout.

Captain Marvel's publishing director (Roscoe Kent Fawcett) was quoted to say:

> "Give me a Superman, only have his other identity be a 10- or
>   12-year-old boy rather than a man"

Wikipedia goes on to say:

> As a result, Captain Marvel was given a 12-year-old boy named Billy
>   Batson as his alter ego.

They're also [depicted as children](http://images.furycomics.com/viewer/c1/c1a84aa9c632b184d61cb0ac8227ef5c/3.jpg) in [Captain Marvel Adventures #18](http://comicbookplus.com/?dlid=15858).

Comment: +! Good one. I thought of Mary Marvel but I thought she was a teen. Do you have a cite for her and Billy being only 12?

Comment: Made an edit. Not abundantly clear, but sources are hard to come by.

Comment: Not easy to verify age is right. For now, +1, and if nothing further develops I'll mark as accepted in a few days.

Answer (score 18):

Maybe [Astrid Lindgren's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrid_Lindgren) famous character [Pippi Longstocking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pippi_Longstocking) (Pippi Långstrump  in Swedish), a 9-year-old girl with superhuman strength? The Pippi comic books (in Swedish) started in 1957 according to [Drawn & Quarterly](http://www.drawnandquarterly.com/press/2012/02/comic-icons-pippi-longstocking-and-moomin-celebrated-comics-reporter). The first Pippi [novel](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?32003) was published in 1945.

Here is a description of Pippi's superhuman strength from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pippi_Longstocking#Strength):

> Pippi has been described as "the strongest girl in the world", but no explanation is given for her strength. Pippi's strength amazes and confounds people, including the children, though they eventually begin to take it in stride. Pippi herself makes no mention of her extraordinary strength, though she is obviously aware of it. She is not at all violent, and when circumstances require her to protect herself or others, she usually takes great care not to hurt anyone. This is seen in the first book, when she neutralizes five large bullies singlehandedly, and also when she engages two policemen, who were determined to take her to an orphanage against her will, in a game of tag.
>
> She is also seen in the various Pippi Longstocking movies picking up a horse (the books often mention Pippi moving her horse Old Man by carrying him from one place to another), a car, and weights/barbells weighing over 1,000 pounds; she also pulls bars out of a jail window and throws pirates across a room.

I don't know if Pippi was the first, but I'm pretty sure she is the most succesful and famous fictional superpowered 9-year-old girl.

Comment: Pippi wasn't a super hero, but a super rascal!

Answer (score 7):

Little Lotta 1953

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Lotta

First appearance    Little Dot #1 September 1953

[image]

Little Lotta is a fictional character published by Harvey Comics from 1953 to 1972, and then sporadically until 1993...

Like many of Harvey's comic headliners, Lotta was notable for a 'quirky' defining characteristic - in this case, an **insatiable appetite giving rise to superhuman strength**...

Far from being the "unpopular fat kid" stereotype represented in other popular media (such as her contemporary Tubby in Little Lulu) Lotta was depicted as friendly, kind-hearted and always ready to use her tremendous strength for what she deemed as good.

Comment: Is Lotta a pre-teen?

Comment: http://www.viciousgrin.com/writings/womencomic.html Little Lotta published by Harvey Comics in 1955. She was a young girl, roughly the age of eight or nine years old

Comment: was she a superhero?

Answer (score -3):

Power Pack debuted in '84. Katie was pre-teen. Julie and Jack are arguable. Alex was not. Lotta was not quite a superhero. I'm hating these downvotes; prove me wrong.
A major ongoing theme of the series was the relationship between Power Pack and their parents, Jim and Maggie. Unlike superheroes such as Spider-Man or Batman, the Power children were not "conveniently" orphaned and alone; instead, they were part of a loving and supportive family. In spite of this, they decided early in the series to keep their powers and superhero activities completely concealed from their parents. Keeping their powers secret sometimes led the members of Power Pack to deceive their family and friends and to feel guilty about doing so. For instance, in one incident, Julie was forced to allow her school friends to be beaten up by bullies instead of using her powers to defend them.[9] The question of whether or not the powers should be revealed was also an ongoing source of debate among the children. Jack, for instance, found it "cool" to have a secret,[11] while the older and more responsible Julie, who had originally suggested that the powers be concealed from their parents,[12] quickly reversed her opinion and felt that they needed to be told sooner or later. Power Pack readers also argued the matter out in the letter pages.

Comment: While they were pre-teens when they first appeared, their first appearances are far later than characters already mentioned in other answers.

Comment: True, but is lotta a superhero? I really can't think of anyone aside from Katie Power. Why not enlighten me instead of down voting?

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but as mentioned in other comments on your answers, it's likely because you posted the answer without the references.

Comment: Hey, I've been here for 4 days. There's a learning / social curve to most sites

Comment: I'm not sure why you're stuck on Lotta. [The accepted answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/79653/5184) predates both Lotta and Powerpack.

Comment: Your issue here is that you're using your answer as a discussion board, rather than an answer. You even replied to your own answer by editing it with a completely different answer, and still failed to cite any sources for your new answer. There may be a learning curve to most sites, but you can pretty easily learn the format of SE by browsing some of our questions and answers, especially if you don't feel comfortable with the format yet. Don't focus on the downvotes, focus on [writing a good answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: True, I'm working a night hotel manager job and don't have the time to cite everything...

Comment: No worries though, I'll try to get citations before I post...