# When was the first superpowered girl in comics?

Tags: comics, history-of, super-hero

Is there a superpowered girl older than the [Magician from Mars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magician_from_Mars) (1939), that is, if I have my information right?

*[The Spectacular Sisterhood of Superwomen: Awesome Female Characters from Comic Book History](https://www.penguinrandomhouse.ca/books/547000/the-spectacular-sisterhood-of-superwomen-by-hope-nicholson/9781594749490/excerpt)* says that:

> an incident that occurred shortly after her birth. A nurse exposed the infant to cathode rays, causing Jane’s genes to mutate and granting her special powers: anything she wishes for appears out of thin air.

Although, the [International Catalogue of Superheroes](http://www.internationalhero.co.uk/m/magicianjane.htm) says that the powers aren't as immediate as that previous phrasing implies?

> When Jane was six, she discovered she possessed telekinesis and could create things from nothing simply by wishing for them.

---

In regards to pre-teen boys, it seems that [The Prince Of Gamma](https://twitter.com/mightykingcobra/status/1004758232345165824?lang=en) or [Sarutobi Sasuke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sarutobi_Sasuke) would be the oldest, if I allow kamishibai and this Tweet is accurate, or if I allow [Kōdan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C5%8Ddan), respectively:

> One of the earliest superheroes of Japan, first seen in 1930s kamishibai paper theatre, he is an alien prince whose secret identity is a street waif who wanders the streets of Tokyo; though seemingly as mighty as Superman, he is still a mere child.

---

So, are there older-than-1939 publications with superpowered pre-teen girls? Not specifically [superheroines](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/79601/what-is-the-first-occurrence-of-a-pre-teen-female-superhero-in-comics), but superpowers in general.

If they're only temporarily empowered? Still fine. If they're villains? Still fine. If they're a gender-bender mixed with youthening of an adult superpowered man? Still fine.

The younger the better, if publication dates are similar.

Comment: Is this the same question? [What is the first occurrence of a pre-teen female superhero in comics?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/79601/what-is-the-first-occurrence-of-a-pre-teen-female-superhero-in-comics) Perhaps your 1939 example should be posted as an answer to that question.

Comment: @user14111 - Oh, right. I need to be more specific in differentiating. Just wanting Superpowers here, not Superhero.